# Java Generic return type method derived to be object return type

Tags: java, generics, type-erasure

I was encountered this wired issue.

```
class Foo<R, C> {

    public C fooMethod() {
        Bar bar = new Bar();
        Map<String, String> m = new HashMap<>();
        return bar.barMethod(m);
    }
}

class Bar {
    public <T> T barMethod(Map<String, String> m) {
        Object barObj = null;
        ...
        return (T) barObj;
    }
}
```

If I declare `m` to be a raw type `Map m = new Map()`, I get a compile error:

> incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to C, where C is a
>   type-variable.

but if `m` is a typed object as declared above, then the compile error is gone.

I can't figure out why the parameter will make a different for compiler to figure out what the return type is. And to me the compiler should not think the generic type T in the Bar class example to be a Object type under any circumstances. Can some one point out where I'm wrong? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce this.

Comment: @JacobG. Hi Jacob, that's where I don't understand, why the type-erasure thinks it's an object type but not generic type C ?

Comment: Interestingly, the problem is not due to type inference, since it stands even when explicitly setting T to C with `return bar.<C>barMethod(m);`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Map m = new HashMap<>();
return bar.barMethod(m); //error
```

The error is thrown because `barMethod(Map<String, String> m)` specifically requires a `Map<String, String>`. You can do a couple of things to make the compile error dissaper.

- **Change `barMethod` parameter to a raw type.**

  ```
  public <T> T barMethod(Map m) {...}
  ```

  OR
- **Cast return value to `C` in the method `fooMethod`**

  ```
  return (C) bar.barMethod(m);
  ```

  OR
- **Change the return type of the method `fooMethod` to Object**

  ```
  public Object fooMethod()
  ```

Comment: The error is not about the parameter type, it's about the return type of this method cannot be cast to generic type C in my case

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any source in the spec but basically, because you've used the raw type `Map` in place of the generic `Map<String, String>`, Java converts **all** generic parameters (not just the `Map`) to the type-erased `Object`. The method signature effectively becomes:

```
public Object barMethod(Map<Object, Object> m)
```

Because `barMethod` returns an `Object`, and `Object` is not necessarily a `C` (as returned by `fooMethod`), the types are incompatible. That's why this results in a compiler error.

Comment: The error remains even if T is explicitly set to C with `return bar.<C>barMethod(m);` How do you explain that?

Comment: @Marco Like I said, you're either using the fully generic version or you're using the fully raw version. Java is ignoring the `<C>` (and its redundant in either case)

Comment: Why isn't generic type <C> got type-erased to Object in this case?

Comment: It's a different method call